# jquery.wysiwyg work with mvc2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, wysiwyg

I'm using jquery.wysiwyg (https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg) with MVC2. How can I get the value of textarea?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<NotificationsViewModel>" %>
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#Message').wysiwyg();
       });
</script>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ManageNotifications", "Admin", FormMethod.Post)) 
{ %>
  <table class="noborderverticalcenter" style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td>Message</td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message) %>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helpful

```
var textContent=$("#textarea-id").wysiwyg('getContent');
```

This will give u text including html tags

to strip html tag use ethis

```
textContent=textContent.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
```